# Adding Value FromArray in Reactive Forms of Angular

Tags: angular

**AdminPanelComponent.ts**

```
    import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
    import {AdminService} from '../sevices/admin.service';
    import {FormBuilder, FormArray, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-admin-panel',
      templateUrl: './admin-panel.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./admin-panel.component.scss']
    })
    export class AdminPanelComponent implements OnInit {
      fieldId: number;
      imageMsg: string;
      uniFormGroup: FormGroup;
      constructor(private adService: AdminService, private formBuild: FormBuilder) {
        this.uniFormGroup = this.formBuild.group({
          uniName: ['', Validators.required],
          location: ['', Validators.required],
          ownership: ['Select Ownership'],
          estdate: ['', [Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(4)]],
          approvals: ['Select Approvals/Recognition'],
          uniType: ['Select University Type'],
          accreditation: ['Select Accreditation'],
          memberAIU: ['Member Of AIU'],
          admissionProcess: [''],
          highlights: [''],
          contact: this.formBuild.group({
            address: [''],
            website: [''],
          }),
          mobile: this.formBuild.array([this.mobileGroup()]),
          email: this.formBuild.array([this.emailGroup()]),
          scholarship: [''],
          facilities: [''],
          googleLoc: this.formBuild.group({
            lat: [''],
            lng: [''],
          }),
        });
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      showEditModal(id, uniName) {
        this.universityName = uniName;
        this.fieldId = id;
        this.editModal.show();
        this.adService.getEditTabels('university', this.fieldId).subscribe((data: any) => {
          const facility = data.facilities.split(',');
          this.uniFormGroup.patchValue({
            uniName: data.uniName,
            location: data.location,
            ownership: data.ownership,
            estdate: data.estdate,
            approvals: data.approvals,
            uniType: data.uniType,
            accreditation: data.accreditation,
            memberAIU: data.memberAIU,
            admissionProcess: data.admissionProcess,
            highlights: data.highlights,
            scholarship: data.scholarship,
            contact: JSON.parse(data.contact),
            facilities: facility,
          });
        });
      }
      mobileGroup(): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuild.group({
          mNumber: ['', [Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.minLength(10), Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')]],
          mtitle: ''
        });
      }
      emailGroup(): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuild.group({
          emailAddress: ['', Validators.email],
          etitle: ''
        });
      }
    }
```

i want assign value to `mobile` FormArray
After HTTP request i receive the mobile like that

```
    [
       {
           "mNumber":"9800000098","mtitle":"office"
       }, 
       {
           "mNumber":"9800000098","mtitle":"Dean"
       }
]
```

Please tell how add this value in reactive FromArray of FromBuilder 
i have not adds value in FromArray. I am Directly assign the it is not accessible this from array Please any suggestions to add the code in `showEditModal()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use setValue() method to assign values to formArray.

```
this.uniFormGroup.get('mobile').controls[0].get('emailAddress').setValue('test data');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare class or interface.

   ```ts
   export interface MobileData {
       mNumber: number,
       mtitle: string,
   }
   ```
2. Declare varibales in component.

   ```ts
    mobileArr: FormArray;
    numberList: MobileData[] = [];
   ```
3. Fill list when you get result from request in subscription.

   ```html
   this.numberList = data;
   ```
4. Modify html like below.

   ```html
   <div class="row" formArrayName="mobileArr">
       <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let m of numberList;  ">       
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   {{m.mNumber}} 
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   {{m.mtitle}}
               </div>
           </div>                  
       </div>
   </div>
   ```